# Стык вводного с ложным вводным?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Боюсь своим вмешательством изменить если не смысл, то акцент (переместить)...

У автора:

> Принц правда, в крайнем случае, может вскочить и быстро ретироваться.

А если так:

*Принц, правда в крайнем случае, может вскочить и быстро ретироваться.*

Ситуация: двое на авансцене; принц своё сказал (свободен), дальше реплика Алёнушки (не убежишь).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В авторском варианте принц в случае чего может убежать, а после редактуры он может это сделать лишь в крайнем случае. Так что, по-моему,  смысл немного меняется. Особенно это заметно, если обособление вынести в конец. Сравните:

> Принц правда может вскочить и быстро ретироваться, в крайнем случае.
>
> Принц может вскочить и быстро ретироваться, правда в крайнем случае.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется.А почему "правда" - ложное вводное?  Здесь же неуверенность, а не "на самом деле"? По-моему, это вводное, а вот "в крайнем случае" - обстоятельство: может вскочить и быстро ретироваться (когда?) в крайнем случае.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы оставила предложение без изменения:

**Принц правда, в крайнем случае, может вскочить и быстро ретироваться.**

Сравнить: Принц правда может вскочить и быстро ретироваться.

**ПРАВДА** IV. в зн. союза. **Хотя**. Иногда, п. редко, мы встречаемся. Послышались шаги, п. ещё далёкие.  Пример: Правда (= но, хотя) есть один момент...

**"В крайнем случае"** (по справочнику "Трудные случаи пунктуации") ― наречие, которое обычно не обособляется, но в данном случае его лучше обособить как вставочную реплику (удобная для обособления позиция, второй план речи).

Кроме того, из двух рядом стоящих слов "правда" и "в крайнем случае" одно нужно обособить.